# Check a value against a list of possible values

Tags: python, list

I need something that checks the length of a list. Maybe something like this, but this does not work:

```
if len(list) != 1 or 2:
   # Do something

if len(list) == 1 or 2:
   # Do something different
```

Ok i figured this out myself:

```
if len(list) == 1:
   # Do something
elif len(list) == 2:
   # Do the same something

if len(list) != 2:
   # Do something different
elif len(list) != 1:
   # Do something different
```

Comment: do you need the comparison to be a range, or a list of possible numbers? Like would you ever do something if it equaled 1,2,5, or 6?

Comment: No, just a single number

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
if 1 <= len(list) <= 2:
    ...
```

or:

```
if len(list) in (1, 2):
    ...
```

should work

Comment: I shall quickly try this thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Well it seems that your second suggestion is returning True or False...

Comment: Both of these are returning true or false

Comment: I simply want the number of elements within the list

Comment: To get the length of a list you can just call `len(myList)`. You should also refrain from using "list" as the identifier for your list since it is reserved for the list command in Python.